# Elm: How to render each elm module in it's own browser window? - both module in the same app (main module)

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, elm

I have a multi monitor setup (with **4 monitors**) and i want to build **an app that will span across 3 of them** like so: -- all monitors are in `extend mode`.
[image]

It's a web app, so it must be inside a browser window. I don't know how to make a chrome window in this shape. From what i see, a browser window must have a rectangular shape.

I can't modify the design of the app, i tried many layouts.. I don't want to lose functionality... having all this monitors is just bad i can't do what i want with all the space. So the final layout **must be something like this red shape you see above**..

Instead of having a big fat chrome window that will take all 4 monitors (and also hiding my terminal or some other program - behind it), i think it's a good idea to split my app in multiple smaller chrome windows - based on functionality.

For example:

```
-- main module - this holds my app
   -- module 1
   -- module 2
   -- module 3
   -- module 4 .. etc
```

I want them sort of like this: 
[image]
- same app, multiple components/modules in multiple chrome windows.

If i arrange them closer together, and hide the window( minimize button, close button etc..), visually i get a very nice app in the shape i want.

Chrome supports this multiple window on the same app behavior.. You can see it in developer console - where you modify something in Style Css panel and the page updates in real time.

Developer Tools somehow communicates with the Page. - maybe it not what i need - but **this ideea of modifying something inside app from another completely different window** is present. Chrome developer tools is browser based - and also can be opened as a separate window.

Related to this behavior -  i found [this library](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js), with [this demo](http://jcubic.pl/sysend.php)  -  which let's you pass information between 2 Chrome windows at the same domain - **but it's exactly the same app, same content!**  **Not parts of a bigger app.**.. that's the problem.  What I want, is 2 windows ***with different content*** - to communicate - like the Developer Tools with the WebPage.

The elm architecture is well suited for communicating changes - but i don't know how can i realize an update across all my windows. If i click something on monitor 1 module 4, i want to see the result in monitor 2 module 2.

**Questions:**

1. Is this even possible? At all - not just elm - but in general.. can be done in JavaScript?
2. Any ideas to adapt it with elm architecture?
3. given that is possible, but not compatible with elm architecture. If i choose to build completely separate elm apps - for each piece of functionality / for each module - how can i make them communicate with no lag? I can use a server of course, but even a 60-100ms delay is not an option here. Must be as real-time as possible.

I'm in the dark. Any ideas are welcomed:)

Comment: Would building your app in [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) be an option? It looks like there are a few different ways to get inter-window communication. You could still use Elm for the front-end with Electron.

Comment: Hmm thanks @Chad Gilbert, looks promising... i will came back with an answer :)

Comment: @Chad Gilbert Electron is definitely the way to go when doing this sort of stuff. It also has access to the Os API trough Node.js. Things like Closing / minimizing Windows, Notifications, File-System etc. Your comment introduced me to Electron Land and it's amazing !!

Answer (score 1):

You might give a shot at using [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) for sharing context between different tabs. This API is fairly new, so it might have some implications.

A simpler alternative is [Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent)

In short, you can listen for changes in Local Storage.

```
let counter = 0;

if (window.localStorage.getItem('counter') === null) {
  setInterval(
    () => {
      document.body.innerText = counter;
      window.localStorage.setItem('counter', counter)
      counter++
    },
    1000
  )
} else {
  window.addEventListener('storage', event => {
    document.body.innerText = event.newValue;
  })
}
```

Try opening this [JS Bin demo](https://jsbin.com/henukaz/edit?js,output) in multiple tabs(remember to flush your storage, if you want to check it out twice).

Itegrate your Elm app with all this magic using [JavaScript Interop](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) and you are all set.